# Java Convert from Scientific Notation to Float

Tags: java, floating-point, scientific-notation

I have a program that I am working on which would effectively convert binary, decimal, or hex numbers to other formats (don't ask why I'm doing this, I honestly don't know). So far I only have a binary - decimal conversion going, and it works fine however whenever the binary number entered is 8 digits or more it crashes.

As far as I can tell when I input the number 10011001 it gets translated to scientific notation and becomes 1.0011001E7 which wouldn't really be a problem, except that the way I am converting the numbers involves creating a string with the same value as the number and breaking it into individual characters. Unfortunately, this means I have a string valued "1.0011001E7" instead of "10011001", so when I cut up the characters I hit the "." and the program doesn't know what to do when I try to make calculations with that. So basically my question comes down to this, how do I force it to use the not-scientific notation version for these calculations?

Thanks for all your help, and here is the code if it helps at all:

```
//This Splits A Single String Of Digits Into An Array Of Individual Digits
public float[] splitDigits(float fltInput){
    //This Declares The Variables
    String strInput = "" + fltInput;
    float[] digit = new float[strInput.length() - 2];
    int m = 0;


    //This Declares The Array To Hold The Answer
    for (m = 0; m < (strInput.length() - 2); m++){
        digit[m] = Float.parseFloat(strInput.substring(m, m + 1)); //Breaks here
    }

    //This Returns The Answer
    return digit;
}
```

Comment: The input should come as a string, not a number.

Comment: Hmm, in retrospect I probably shouldn't have converted it to a number until after I split up the digits. Thanks, I didn't realize I could've just left it as a String, that one was staring me in the face.

Answer (score 6):

Just use [BigDecimal](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1,5.0/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html)

```
BigDecimal num = new BigDecimal(fltInput);
String numWithNoExponents = num.toPlainString();
```

Note here the fltInput will be automatically converted to a double.

Comment: This worked for up to 8 or 9 digits, which is definitely an improvement, but after that it would round off. Somehow "111111111" = 111111167. Not sure how that happened, but once I left it as a String it worked itself out. Thanks for the help though.

Comment: No problem. Leaving it as a string is definitely the preferred way to deal with both BigInteger and BigDecimal, but your method signature started you off with a float and I didn't want to assume you had access to the data as a string. I'm glad it worked for you.